# chef receipe to add values to mysql table

Tags: mysql, chef-infra, chef-recipe

i have a chef recipe to monitor a service is running or not with the following data

```
service = "test"
if ::Win32::Service.exists?(service)
  service "test" do
    action [:enable, :start]
  end
else
  windows_package "test" do
    source "\\10.10.10.10\test.exe"
    installer_type :custom
    options 'install ip=10.10.10.11'
  end
end
```

i need to add this values to a remote mysql table (mysql server ip 10.10.10.12) so that i can create an html or php page for reporting.

Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

You would do this the same way as by hand, usually with a something built in to your web framework or otherwise an `execute` resource running the `mysql` command line tool.